# angularjs 2 table cell styling

Tags: angular, html-table

I'm trying to change the color of selected cells dynamically in a table.

Following is the template code.

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let eachRow of rowsInAMonth">
        <td *ngFor="let eachDay of eachRow;" (click)="selectedDates(eachDay)" 
                    [style.color]="eachDay.color">
{{eachDay ? eachDay.date : ''}}       
</td>
       </tr>    
</tbody>
```

Getting an error saying:

> inline template:23:20 caused by: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50

Appreciate any help

Comment: Because eachDay is undefined. Can you provide more code

Comment: But (click)="selectedDates(eachDay)" works fine. It gets the current selected object. I'm new to Angular 2. Why is the current object eachDay not accessible for ngStyle